# Unable to read in files in Python 2.7.4 with open(sys.argv[])

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am within the Python environment in my Terminal on my Mac (OS Lion).

The python script contains the following lines,

```
def main():
    file1 = open(sys.argv[1])
    file2 = open(sys.argv[2])
    file3 = open(sys.argv[3])
```

I assume that that I need to run the script by doing:

```
script.py file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

But I keep getting the error message below:

```
>>> process.py output1.txt output2.txt output3.txt
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    process.py output1.txt output2.txt output3.txt
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

All the files and the script are in the current working directory (I checked it by `import os`, and run `print os.getcwd()`. Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot run python scripts from within python itself.

You need to start the script from the command line:

```
 python script.py file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Comment: shouldnt this say " you cannot run python scripts with sys.arguments from within python itself " ?

Comment: ok, barring `eval` and friends, you cannot run python scripts. `sys.argv` doesn't really matter for what the OP did, only if you try `execfile` it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Command Prompt or Bash shell.

Do.

`python scriptName.py < Space Seperated Arguments >`

Answer (score 1):

It looks from the prompt as though you're trying to run your script from within the Python interpreter, i.e. you are typing `python` and then at the python `>>>` prompt you are entering your script name and parameters. That prompt is meant to be for typing actual Python commands at interactively.

If you exit the Python interpreter and just type in your script name and parameters at the normal shell prompt, that will work (as long as you have `#!/usr/bin/python` as the first line of your script).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to use your script programmatically from within Python, a slight alteration to your `main` function to accept arguments will let you do it.  E.g.,

```
def main(*argv):
    file1 = open(argv[1])
    file2 = open(argv[2])
    file3 = open(argv[3])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(*sys.argv)
```

This gives you much more flexibility, letting you call your program from the command line but also within a program like:

```
import process
process.main("output1.txt", "output2.txt", "output3.txt")
```